# How to deal with it/sl/bold in lmtt?

Tags: fonts, italic, typewriter, latin-modern

I just stumbled upon the fact that the font `lmtt` (latin modern typewriter) seems to exist in

- italic
- slanted
- bold
- bold slanted

but not

- bold italic

At least the file `t1lmtt.fd` contains the lines

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmtt}{m}{it}
     {<-> ec-lmtti10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmtt}{m}{sl}
     {<-> ec-lmtto10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmtt}{b}{sl}
{<-> ec-lmtko10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmtt}{b}{it}
     {<->sub*lmtt/b/sl}{}
```

which, upon naïve use, leads to the rather unpleasant result

[image: sl vs it]

At the moment, my clumsy fix for this is

```
\input{t1lmtt.fd}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmtt}{m}{it}
     {<-> sub*lmtt/m/sl}{}
```

which means I get slanted typewriter (instead of italic) everywhere.

What would be a better alternative?

Mind you, I'm not complaining the bold italic font seems to be missing.

AFAICS the family `cmtt` doesn't really have any bold fonts anyway, so another obvious alternative would be to map *bold italic* to *medium italic* also for `lmtt`.

Comment: I think using slanted everywhere  for monospace italic is OK. italic typewriter is a distinctly odd concept anyway:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So this seems to be the way to go. Now that I worked with this setting a bit, I rather like it :-) Could you turn your comment into an answer? Maybe you have some advice for how to achieve this in a more canonical way than I did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think using slanted everywhere for monospace italic is OK. *`Italic typewriter`* is a distinctly odd concept anyway:-)  The substitution in the font shape is as good a way as any to achieve this.

Comment: This looks good when using italics inside a typewriter block. However, I find it looks quite odd when using typewriter inside a larger italic block :(